# Feasibility of vendoring binary executables within a gem?

Tags: ruby, heroku, rubygems, rake

I've written a sprockets processor for losslessly compressing jpgs and pngs, you check it out it here: https://github.com/botandrose/sprockets-image_compressor

However, I can't use this gem on heroku, because the jpegoptim and pngcrush programs aren't available within their environment. Furthermore, users of the gem will need to remember to install these programs on every system they want to use my gem. So, I think it'd be nice if I could vendor in these binaries as a fallback if the system doesn't have them installed already.

So, is this totally crazy? Would I need to provide a 64bit binary as well as a 32bit? Would I still require some sort of external library to be installed? Would I be better off writing some sort of C extension that hooks into these programs?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen many gems in the wild that do this sort of thing. One other option, however, is to provide rake tasks that go out and fetch the programs if they aren't already installed on the machine. It might be tricky to make it work for all the different platforms, though.

Answer (score 0):

With regard to using your gem on Heroku: remember that Heroku has a read-only filesystem (except for the `/tmp` directory), so running Sprockets processors like yours on Heroku isn't really a practicable option anyways. I personally just use `rake assets:precompile` and commit all the precompiled assets to my Git repo before pushing to Heroku. Yes, I know it messes up the repo history, but it's the easiest way to go (at least for now). Hopefully Heroku will come up with some other option in the future.

As far as the main question you asked, hopefully someone else can provide a good answer. Your project looks very cool; I am just going to try it out.